# inserting select into select

Tags: oracle, plsql

I need to get username for selected `party_id`, but I need to insert instead of 
`party_id`, I tries with nested sub queries but always get in stuck with brackets.

I have this select instead of `gm.party_id` in second select:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  select gm.party_id, sum(gm.game_out)
  from game_record gm
  where gm.party_id in (
    select cs.party_id
    from casino_users cs
    where cs.parent_id=get_party_id_from_promo(619)
  ) 
  group by party_id
  order by sum(game_out) desc
)
WHERE ROWNUM <= 10;
```

I need to insert this select:

```
select username
from casino_users
where party_id in (
  select cs.party_id
  from casino_users cs
  where cs.parent_id=get_party_id_from_promo(619)
)
```

Also I have function which returns username from `party_id` but when I try to compile it I get an invalid identifier error in the first select.

```
FUNCTION get_top_ten_highscore(p_promo_code number) RETURN WEAK_CUR IS
 resault_set weak_cur;

begin

 open resault_set for

     SELECT * FROM (
       select username_from_id (gm.party_id) as party_id, sum(gm.game_out)
       from game_record gm
       where gm.party_id in (
         select cs.party_id
         from casino_users cs
         where cs.parent_id=get_party_id_from_promo(619)
       ) 
       group by party_id
       order by game_out desc)
    WHERE ROWNUM <= 10;
    return  resault_set ;

end get_top_ten_highscore;
```

Comment: So you want a list of what exactly? The top ten parties with all their users, i.e. a list of, say, 100 rows, each with a party and its gameout sum and a user attending the party? Can you post an example?

Comment: Why did you roll back boneist's edit, to something that is not formatted properly or easy to read?

Comment: I want instead of gm.party_id to get username ..

Comment: That doesn't fully answer my question. Do you only want a list of users that took part in the top 10 parties? No party ID in your results? Only users?

Comment: Yes, i want list of usernames and sum(game_out ) in top 10.

Comment: Change your group by clause. You can not use alias name in group by clause.

Comment: Update your question add  proper data sample and the exptctedc result  ..

Comment: I still don't understand. The `sum(game_out)` is a sum per party. You want to work with the top ten parties. Let's say parties A and B are in the top 10. A has a sum of 200, B a sum of 100. Party A had two users x and z. Party B had two users, y and z. So what do you display in your results? x-200, y-100, z-300? Or x-200, y-100, z-200, z-100? Or what else?

Comment: Correct, sum is per party.. No party_id is unique so there cant be two username s under one party_id...
 I have problem just getting username from party id.. When i run just a select from the function get_top_ten_highscore i get results but when i create function i get error

Comment: I just need to separate  select gm.party_id, sum(gm.game_out) from game_record into two selects. instead of gm.party_id should go   select username from casino_users where party_id in (select cs.party_id from casino_users cs where cs.parent_id=load_beting_data.get_party_id_from_promo(619)) and sum(gm.game_out) should be the same

Comment: Only one user per party? Why then `casino_users.party_id` which allows for multiple users, and not `party.user_id` which would allow only one user per party? It seems your assumptions about your data are wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a JOIN

```
    SELECT 
      select gm.party_id, sum(gm.game_out), cs.username
      from game_record gm
      INNER JOIN  casino_users cs ON cs.parent_id=get_party_id_from_promo(619)
      WHERE ROWNUM <= 10;
      group by gm.party_id, cs.username
      order by sum(game_out) desc
```

Comment: it cant help i get just one row with 0 sum

Comment: as request before  ...  update your question add  a proper data sample and the expected  result

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM (
            select (select USERNAME FROM CASINO_USERS CU WHERE CU.PARTY_ID = gm.party_id) as username, 
            sum(gm.game_out) from game_record gm 
            where  gm.party_id in (select cs.party_id from casino_users cs where cs.parent_id=load_beting_data.get_party_id_from_promo(619)
            and party_id not in (7808,7810,7817,7818,7819,7821,7824,7825,7827,7823,7830,7812,7822,7831,7826,7829,7809,7811,7820,7828)) 
            group by party_id
            order by sum(game_out)  desc
            )
    WHERE ROWNUM <= 10;
```